# Sign out from remote Android's Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, authentication

Last week I lost my phone, so I borrowed a phone from a friend.
The phone already add the Gmail app with my friend's Gmail account (a Gmail account that my friend does not care much about so there was no privacy issue). I added my Gmail account into the app so that I could check my emails.

**Problem**: I had to take a plane in a rush and forgot to sign out from my Google account on that phone.

**Question**: How do I sign out myself?

- I could just ask my friend, but I would prefer something more reliable (and that does not trigger their curiosity).
- On a desktop computer I clicked "*Details*" then "*Sign out all other Gmail web sessions*", but it only says "*web*" so that probably does not sign out mobile sessions? By the way, my friend's device does not show up in this list.
- On a desktop computer I changed my password, but that did not sign me out of Gmail on my own phone (yes I found it back!), so I guess that does not sign me out of Gmail on my friend's phone either?

At https://myaccount.google.com/security "*Your devices*" still shows my friend's phone (*screenshot on Firefox 66.0.3 JavaScript enabled addons disabled*):

[image]

The date and time shown in the screenshot above is well after I left. The "*Lost this device?*" page only gives useless advice such as "*Try calling your phone*" or "*Reach out to your carrier*", with no button to remove that session.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage all devices on the [Device Activity](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) web page:

[image: Screenshot]

Expand the entry of your lost device and you will get a button for "Remove account access."

Comment: That's precisely the entry shown by my question's screenshot. As you can see, I get no "Remove account access" button.

Comment: @Nicolas I added a screenshot how it looks in my browser. I have the REMOVE button for ever Android device. May be it is a web browser problem? The screenshot is from latest Firefox with JavaScript enabled, no plugins/addons installed. Or it means that the account was already removed from the device.